# Mac - switch all desktops at once

Tags: macos

I can use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   and the left/right arrows to switch individual desktops on a multiscreen system but can you switch **all** of them at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by disabling "Displays have separate Spaces"

System Prefs > Mission Control

[image]

Comment: Bit of a shame but it feels like a feature when I disable it!

Comment: tbh, It drove me mad for one whole day when it was first introduced, in, I think, Mavericks. It's been off ever since.